# Is there a better way to attach to pageshow in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates, jquery-mobile

I have a function that I need to call whenever a page is displayed, whether that is through a standard page load or through jQuery Mobile's AJAX navigation mechanism.  Currently, my code works without issue, but I feel like there is a more elegant way.

In the footer of my page I have some code that attaches to the `pageshow` event for that page.  On `pageshow` it will focus on a textbox, do an alert (for testing), and then unbind itself from the `pageshow` event.  If I don't unbind, then if I navigate away from the page and then back to it, the event will fire twice.  Not really a big deal for the focus event, but if you try this with alerts you see them start to stack up :P

```
var focusOnQuantity = function () {
    $("#quantity").focus();
    alert('test');
    $('body').undelegate('#reportProduction', 'pageshow', focusOnQuantity);
};

// Bind to this page's pageshow event when loaded via jQuery Mobile AJAX
$('body').delegate('#reportProduction', 'pageshow', focusOnQuantity);
```

I also have a global JS and inside that I have a jQuery protection function where I make the same focus call in the case that this page is loaded directly.

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        // For direct page load
        $("#quantity").focus();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I encapsulate the code into 1 block so that it will work on `pageload` for standard navigation, and `pageshow` for AJAX navigation?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just bind to the `pageshow` event it will fire on the initial load as well as each subsequent `pageshow`:

```
$(document).delegate('#reportProduction', 'pageshow', focusOnQuantity);
```

If this code is run in the global scope it should only run once per `pageshow` event on the `#reportProduction` page.

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/DHeva/ (notice that I have changed the "onLoad" preference to "no wrap (body)" which means that the code is appended to the end of the `body` element without using a `$(function () {...});`).

Comment: So I need to do this on the "main" page that is loaded... Is there anyway for me to include scripts inside the sub page?

Comment: From my end it seems like your code to bind to the `pageshow` event is nested within some other event handler that gets called periodically so the bindings to the `pageshow` event add-up. I could confirm this with more complete examples of code or a link to the page.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was, It's working now... basically I just moved the code to the footer of the sub-page that was being loaded and everything is working now.  The only thing I'm doing differently that I can think of is that I'm removing the page from the cache: 
$('body').delegate('div.ui-page', 'pagehide', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });